# SWT Displaying HTML with ContentProposalAdapter

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

So I'm looking at this `InfoPopupDialog`, which is an inner class of `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.ContentProposalAdapter`.

From what I'm seeing here, the secondary popup/extra info/description is displayed as text.

[image]

BUT in Eclipse's content proposal, a javadoc is displayed nicely (I'm guessing with HTML formatting) in the secondary popup.

**Question**: Are they using a different mechanism? How do I display HTML in the extra info popup?

Answer (score 0):

The nicely formatted popups are done with the `org.eclipse.jface.text` classes `DefaultInformationControl`, `CompletionProposalPopup`, `ContentAssistant` and others which are all oriented to dealing with the JFace text editor code.

I don't see a way to connect this to `ContentProposalAdapter`.

Comment: Wow, how are these so different and do the same thing?